# compare a substring of variable with another string in unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed, grep, ksh

I am a beginner in Unix. My apologies if the question sounds too lame.

I will be passing an argument to a variable `fullstring=$1`. The input for this variable might be something similar to these options, for example tester.txt or tester.sh or testapiece.zip or testing.bad or `*.*`    Basically it is something like the string containing the filename wildcard pattern along with file type.

Here I need to cut just the file type from the string that is passed in the argument i.e. basically i need to cut the string from "." till the end and I need to compare it with multiple strings in the IF clause.

Code structure outline will be similar to the below structure:

```
IF substring of variable(just the filetype in the variable)  is not equals to any of the set of 4 predefined file type strings (txt,zip,csv,*)
THEN 
     ECHO "file is not in the required file type"
     EXIT
ELSE
     ECHO "file is in required file type"
FI
```

It will be helpful if some one can help me with the condition to compare in IF clause.  Thanks in advance.

Note: we can pass literal `*` as the file type, it should be compared literally to the `*`

Comment: You probably want basename instead of a regex. And you definitely should write a program to attempt to solve the issue then ask when you run into problems -- stackoverflow is not a platform for requesting algorithm writing.

Comment: Do you want to write this in Bash? Some other shell? The tags are missing a language.

Comment: I want to write this code in KSH

Comment: Hi scott johnson, My apologies. It is actually a bigger code  that i wrote, This IF condition is a part of the full code which i couldn't implement in it. I am not sure whether i can provide the full code. So i just provided more detail in what i am looking for. I am defintely trying to implement this but could not fix it, so reached out for your stackoverflow experts suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: File name extensions are just conventions... a text file isn't _required_ to have a `.txt` extension, `.zip` can mean more than one thing, etc. You can/should check the actual type first, and _then_ check the extension if necessary. You can get the mime-type by using `file --brief --mime <filename>` — if it says "application/zip; charset=binary" you don't really care what the extension is, but if it says "text/plain; charset=<something>" you might care if it's `.csv` or `.txt` or no extension at all.

Comment: wrt `passing an argument to a variable` - you don't pass arguments to variables, you pass arguments to scripts, programs, functions, etc. You assign values to variables. wrt `need to cut just the file type` - there is no "type" in a file name. There CAN be a suffix like ".txt" but that doesn't mean it's a text file, it could be an Excel spreadsheet or anything else. To determine the type of a file you use the command `file` on it to analyze it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

```
str="a.txt"
if [ "${str##*.}" = "txt" ] ; then
    do this
else
    do that
fi
```

`${str##*.}` is a so called parameter expansion. Find more info about that here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99035&seqNum=3

Comment: Thanks.. looking into it

Comment: How should OP tst a set of 4 predefined file types? 4 if-statements, regexpr, use case or egrep?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for single file type but how to test the set of 4 or 5 predefined file types, can i use '||' to compare multiple sets

Comment: Testing for one of multiple extensions can use a [case statement](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) `ext=""${str##*.}"` ... `case ${ext} in` ...`txt)` ... `zip)` etc.