# If condition not returning desired output in unix ksh - returns wrong output

Tags: unix, if-statement, ksh

I am passing a file name as an argument to a script and inside the script I'm extracting the file extension from that file name.

I am trying to verify whether the extension provided is valid by checking it against a list.

The list of valid extensions is: `txt`, `csv`, `zip`, `*`.

Against my expectations, if `$fileext` contains `sh`, the script still indicates that a valid file extension was specified:

```
fileext=${1##*.}

if (("$fileext" == "txt")) || (("$fileext" == "csv")) || (("$fileext" == "zip")) || (("$fileext" == "*"))
then
    echo "$fileext is a proper file extension"
else
    echo "$fileext is not an appropriate file extension"
fi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare a substring of variable with another string in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163452/compare-a-substring-of-variable-with-another-string-in-unix)

Comment: No, Its not a duplicate, here the issue is wrong output is being returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(( ))` is for integer arithmetic. All your strings evaluate to zero numerically and zeros are equal to zeros, hence the positive result of the test.

You can do either:

```
if  [ "$fileext" = "txt" ]  ||  [ "$fileext" = "csv" ]  ||  [ "$fileext" = "zip" ]  ||  [ "$fileext" = "*" ] 
then
    echo "$fileext is a proper file extension"
else
        echo "$fileext is not an appropriate file extension"
fi
```

or

```
case "$fileext" in 
    txt|csv|zip|"*") 
        echo "$fileext is a proper file extension"
        ;;
        *) 
        echo "$fileext is not an appropriate file extension"
        ;;
esac
```

(These snippets should additionally be POSIX and therefore not require special shells such as `ksh`.)